# Flume continue from the same place using tail

Tags: flume

Recently we made several attempts at using flume. Mostly to stream data from our front end servers to back end servers to get processed. It was done by writing local 'log' files and having flume tail them. 
The problem was that upon restarting the flume node all files in the directory got resent. Is there a way to effectively manage this? Can flume give some event that it finished processing a file? Does it have built in checkpointing?

If not, what would be the approach to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you restart flume node, the tailsource will start from the beginning of the file it's tailing. Flume still hasn't solved this problem out of the box yet. You will have to implement a kinda state manage by yourself.

Just give you a quick idea, you can run another thread basically listen to the bytes tailsource has been tailing against the file and persist that bytes_read somewhere. If the flume agent is crashed or restarted, you just read that bytes_read from where you persisted it (eg. a file in the tmp folder). But you will need to wrap the tailsource constructor somehow. It solves the problem in a nasty way while you are waiting the fix from flume itself :(